# Change the distance between the bullet and the text | Api JavaScript for Word

Tags: list, ms-word, office-js, indentation

I need a space after the number in the list. Tell me please, how to do this using Api JavaScript for Word.

In the properties of the `List` object, I can only set the spacing of the paragraph and the indentation of the first line of the paragraph (`setLevelIndents`).

[image]

Comment: Hi there. Your question does not show what you have tried so far so it's unlikely that you will get a high quality answer. Here's the guide how to ask a good question on stackoverflow which will be answered more likely: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The distance between the symbol and the text is the difference between the first and the second properties in the dialog box in the image. The first of these sets the indent of the symbol from the text margin; the second the indent of the text from the text margin. Increase the latter or decrease the former in order to increase the space between symbol and text.

In the Office JS API (API Set Word 1.3) the [corresponding method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.list?view=word-js-preview#setlevelindents-level--textindent--bulletnumberpictureindent-) is `set​Level​Indents`. The method signature

```
set​Level​Indents(level, text​Indent, bullet​Number​Picture​Indent)
```

The second parameter (`textIndent`) corresponds to the second control in the dialog box shown in the question. The third parameter (`bullet​Number​Picture​Indent`) corresponds to the *first* control in that dialog box.